# How do you put the text from a string into code?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a one line JavaScript code software and right now it looks perfectly fine... until you hit the run button. Instead of running the code (like it's supposed to), it does absolutely nothing. So yeah, you can see the problem I am having with this.
Here's my HTML (in case you want to look over it):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="default">
      <input type="text" id="codeInput" placeholder="document.write(`Hello, world!`)" value="document.write(`Hello, world!`)" class="code">
      <br/>
      <button onclick="convertString()">Run</button>
    </div>
    <div class="default">
      <script type="text/javascript" id="code">
        document.write(`Hello, world!`)
      </script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's my JavaScript:

```js
function convertString () {
  let code = document.getElementById("codeInput").value
  document.getElementById("code").innerHTML = code
}
```

And here's my CSS (not sure why I put this in here, but you can look over it if you want to):

```css
.code {
  color: #162;
}
.default {
  display: block;
  margin: 8px;
}
```

So uhh... I'm having trouble. can you please help me?
`<h1>Thank you!</h1>`
Edit 1 (4 Jul 2020): No, this is not the same as [stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml). S/he was trying to use `onload=""` to do a `<script></script>` inside the `onload=""`. I am trying to call a function with a separate run function in my JavaScript and using a separate `<script></script>` tag.

Comment: Where are you including your JavaScript code from your HTML? Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Are any errors thrown in your browser dev tools console? Always check there

Comment: Did you link the JS file containing `convertString` to your HTML file?

Comment: The problem that you are having is you are trying to run javascript by simply using javascript to place it into script tags like it is a string. There is a very frowned upon and potentially dangerous solution for what you are trying to do and that is use `eval` to evaluate and run the code in the box `eval(code)`. Are you the only one that will be entering in the javascript for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml)

Comment: @D.Pardal no... no, i do not

Comment: @MubaraqWahab on playcode, you don't actually need to

Comment: @imvain2 im thinking about making this a website so no

Comment: @imvain2 +, when i tried to use eval(), the thing LITERALLY just said, goodbye!.

Answer (score 2):

In your html code, you're referring to a function (`convertString()`) which is defined outside the html page, in a separate file. You need to reference the JS file from your HTML page

```
<script src="path/to/script.js"/>
```

It is usually better to include JS files at the bottom of the page, in order for the browser to download every other file and start its JS engine at last

Comment: @COArSeD1RTxxx do you have a separate javascript file? Where is your `convertString()` function written? The code I suggested doesn't work because you need to change the path to the source js file

Comment: *sigh*. Yes, I do have a searate javascript file

Answer (score 2):

```js
function convertString() {
  let code = document.getElementById("codeInput").value
  document.getElementById("code").innerHTML = code
}
```

```css
.code {
  color: #162;
}

.default {
  display: block;
  margin: 8px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="default">
    <input type="text" id="codeInput" placeholder="document.write(`Hello, world!`)" value="document.write(`Hello, world!`)" class="code">
    <br/>
    <button onclick="convertString()">Run</button>
  </div>
  <div class="default">
    <div id="code"></div>
  </div>
```

it is not good to called script tag and render something there sometimes it won't work if it is not the JavaScript code

Comment: what you meant m8 is that browser

Comment: no... thats not what i want ***AT ALL***. I am not trying to write a thing. I am trying to make a coding software

Comment: however, you did do a gud

Comment: how do u do dat

Comment: It takes more effort to answer the question so it's good idea to mark it as accepted if you do